# Pick numbers randomly and uniquely until finished from an array list and assign to variables in another list in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I am having a list of numbers that are user specified in an array and I have need to pick each number randomly until all numbers are picked (uniquely) and then assign each number to variables in another array. For example: This list(1,2,3,4) and that list(a, b, c, d, e, f , g). Now after assignment randomly it should be something like g=1, e=3, a=2, f=4. Please also note that the 'that list' has variables that are not of same size as 'this list'. Thanks for the help. I thought of shuffle, putting it in 2 columns of a table in sqlite and shuffling them but simply can't make it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put either your numbers or letters into an `ArrayList` and use `Collections.shuffle()`. Then iterate through both arrays to assign your values. If you don't care about the order of either one, you can shuffle both!